# Tried to recover a Ext4 Superblock to a CEPH disk

Tags: debian, ext4, disaster-recovery, ceph, e2fsck

We have a server with Proxmox installed with Debian, it's an dedicated server (sda). The VM's are being backed up every night on a CEPH disk (sdb). After an reboot of the dedicated, the ext4 drive from the dedicated server had a broken superblock.

In order to restore the ext4 drive I looked up the restorable superblocks with:

```
sudo mke2fs -n /dev/sda
```

[restorable superblocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vT0t.png)

But when I tried to restore the superblock to the sda drive I accidentally tried to restore the superblock from (sda) to the network CEPH drive (sdb) with the following command:

```
sudo e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/sdb
```

Now the CEPH disk is unreadable.

Is there any solution to restore of get the data from the CEPH disk?
I am not very experienced with server stuff. And if I am missing crucial information let met know.